# express.js - basic application router not working

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

I just creating a basic app, but it seems not working for me. any one help me to find the mistake?

here is my code :

```
import express from "express";

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();


app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log("first middleware");
    next();
});

router.get("/a", (req, res, next) => {
    res.send("Hello this is route a");
});

router.post("/c", (req, res, next) => {
    res.send("Hello this is route c");
});

app.listen({ port: 8000 }, () => {
    console.log("Express Node server has loaded");
});
```

Node version : `v14.17.5`
Express version : `^4.17.1`

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the router

```
import express from "express";

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();


router.get("/a", (req, res, next) => {
res.send("Hello this is route a");
});

router.post("/c", (req, res, next) => {
   res.send("Hello this is route c");
});

app.use(router, (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("first middleware");
  next();
});

app.listen({ port: 8000 }, () => {
  console.log("Express Node server has loaded");
});
```

Comment: when i visit to `localhost:8000`, still getting an error as `Cannot GET /` is it some other issue? In console I am getting `Express Node server has loaded` and `first middleware` both

Comment: Yes, works. actually what is the basic mistake i do?

Comment: or create another route for base url as
`router.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
res.send("Hello this is base");
});`

Comment: you created router, but not using that with app

Answer (score 0):

You need the app to consume the router.

Try adding `app.use('/route', router);`

Answer (score 0):

Use app.use

Example

`app.use('/c', c);`